# Is declaring a variable and using it has better performance than getting the variable every time?

Tags: performance

This is kind of naïve question. But still asking.. Considering the following code:

```
func1(obj.state)
func2(obj.state)
func3(obj.state)
func4(obj.state)
```

Does replacing above code with below has any performance improvement or it doesn't matter at all (modern compilers can optimize these things themselves..?).

```
value = obj.state
func1(value)
func2(value)
func3(value)
func4(value)
```

If state was instead a big function that takes some time to compute, then surely second code would have better performance. I'm asking in the case when its just a state.

I thought of this because, in first case it has first go to the reference of object, and then it has to go to reference pointed by state. But in second case it can directly go to the reference pointed by value. It is a tradeoff between space and time.

Also does this differ from language to language?

Comment: Most programming languages are designed so that the cost of accessing a member is minimal.  Some compilers may optimize out the subsequent accesses.  The only way to know for sure is to profile both pieces of code and see which one performs better, if at all.

Comment: It can differ from language to language, but most modern compilers are smart enough to optimize the code above because you keep asking for the value of the same memory address.

Comment: Also, you're shouldn't worry about this at all unless you identify an actual performance problem that you need to solve.

Comment: It also depends on `obj`. Can the compiler prove that the functions do not modify `obj.state` and no other thread does? This is easier if `obj` is a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

Question to you: does better performance matter to you if the result is not correct?

The first code fragment uses latest state for each function call, the second - the same state for all calls. If you know that the state doesn’t change, and if the compiler doesn’t know that - the second fragment is better. Otherwise use the first.